# Task running but not ending with SQLAlchemy operations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm stuck on an issue where my task doesn't go further then the execution of my SQLAlchemy queries:

```py
@task
def metrics_aggregation_task():
    try:
        logging.info("Starting metrics aggregation task")

        logging.info("Initializing engines")
        LANGFUSE_DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("LANGFUSE_DATABASE_URL")
        langfuse_engine = create_engine(LANGFUSE_DATABASE_URL)

        AIRFLOW_DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("AIRFLOW_DATABASE_URL")
        airflow_engine = create_engine(AIRFLOW_DATABASE_URL)

        AUTOMODELLING_DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("MODELLING_DATABASE_URL")
        automodelling_engine = create_engine(AUTOMODELLING_DATABASE_URL)

        # Define the session
        session_automodelling = Session(bind=automodelling_engine)
        session_langfuse = Session(bind=langfuse_engine)
        session_airflow = Session(bind=airflow_engine)

        logging.info("Sessions created")
        product_id_and_run_id_query = """
                SELECT "productId", "id", "metadata"  FROM "Dags"
                """

        logging.info("Fetching product_ids_and_run_ids")
        product_ids_and_run_ids = session_automodelling.execute(
            product_id_and_run_id_query
        ).fetchall()

        logging.info(f"Fetched product_ids_and_run_ids : {product_ids_and_run_ids}")
```

When checking the task's logs, I can see that the previous logs are working, indicating the task is up & running:

```
[2024-03-19, 13:02:58 CET] {metrics_aggregation.py:52} INFO - Starting metrics aggregation task
[2024-03-19, 13:02:58 CET] {metrics_aggregation.py:54} INFO - Initializing engines
[2024-03-19, 13:02:58 CET] {metrics_aggregation.py:69} INFO - Sessions created
[2024-03-19, 13:02:58 CET] {metrics_aggregation.py:74} INFO - Fetching product_ids_and_run_ids
```

I'm not exactly sure why this occurs. I reckon it's related to some async operation happening with the `Session` but I don't know what's the right way forward.

The code is wrapped with a try/except block, but no errors are raised, it's like if the code was waiting for a fulfilled operation.
The DAG & task both work when using `airflow dags test <dag_id>` or `airflow tasks test <task_id>`. This problem specifically occurs at runtime on the Airflow scheduler/webserver.

Comment: As I understand a database connection is not actually made until the first operation, ie. `SELECT`.  So its possible the database connection is not working or is going to timeout.  I would try turning on `echo=True` on the engine and maybe try setting a timeout for the correct driver you are using to get more information [special-keyword-arguments-passed-to-dbapi-connect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#special-keyword-arguments-passed-to-dbapi-connect)